# Invoking button click event on one page from another page ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have two aspx pages i.e. default1.aspx and default2.aspx. Default1 contains some controls, tables etc. I am showing Default2.aspx into anthor window using hyperlink, setting its target to _blank. What I need is to call a button event which is placed inside Default1.aspx as soon as Default2 is closed (i.e. as soon as the new window showing default2 is closed).

Although, I know that this can be accomplished by showing the default2 into a modal popup i.e. show the default2 into a modal dialog and after that call the button event using javascript. But due to some reasons i am not permitted to do that.

Could some one please show me how i could do that.

Comment: do you need default1 and default2 open at same time?

Comment: ofcourse, thats why i am showing default2 into new window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I was you, I'd refactor what will the button in page 1 do in a helper method that both of pages can call.

Comment: Thanks Fabiran! ok, is there any way to notify default1 that default2 is closed?

Comment: Hard to say. Don't forget that web programming is stateless. You should consider setting a flag somewhere to get the answer. IMHO, if you come to this kind of trick, it probably denotes a flaw in your design.